# How to force jayway-jsonpath to keep string as string (not integer)

Tags: java, string, integer, jsonpath

A need to parse different database-values stored as json. These may be complex (Java-)types or single values (String, doubles, integers...).

When parsing `{"value":"01234"}` with javapath it always tries to convert the 'value'-attribute to an integer. Is there any way to suppress this and keep it as a string?

In case it is really `{"value": 56789}`, it should be returned as a integer.
As I don't know the type in advance, I would like jsonpath to keep the value as it was stored in json.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the JsonOrgJsonProvider and this helped me out.
Had done this before (together with some of the others) but ran into another error, what I hadn't seen.